# Rails 3 plugin scope_out doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey,
I'm tried to install the scope_out plugin through "rails plugin install http://scope-out-rails.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/"

and added scope_out to a model of mine:

```
class MessageCopy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :folder
  delegate   :author, :created_at, :subject, :body, :recipients, :to => :message
  scope_out  :deleted
  scope_out  :not_deleted, :conditions => ["deleted IS NULL OR deleted = ?", false]
end
```

but I always get the error:
    undefined method `scope_out'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scope_out` plugin is not compatible with Rails3.

Judging from the explanation of the plugin, it may very well be obsolete now. Instead, you can write those scopes as:

```
class MessageCopy < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :deleted, where(:deleted => true)
  scope :not_deleted, where("deleted IS NULL OR deleted = ?", false)
end
```

More information about the new ActiveRelation syntax [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions).

You can write this using raw ARel objects as well:

```
where( arel_table[:deleted].eq(nil).or( arel_table[:deleted].eq(false) ) )
```

I've been using a new gem called [MetaWhere](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) to augment standard ARel. It would let you write `not_deleted` as:

```
scope :not_deleted, where({ :deleted => nil } | { :deleted => false })
```

If you're using Rails 3.1, try out the successor to MetaWhere called [Squeel](http://metautonomo.us/projects/squeel/)

```
scope :not_deleted, where{ ( deleted == nil ) | ( deleted == false ) }
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to point out where does the `scope.or(scope)` syntax comes from ?

Comment: @clyfe now that you mention it, MetaWhere might be adding that. I'll update the answer.